# Making connection to dynamic URL with jsoup after making a session

Tags: java, cookies, web, jsoup, rft

Need help with making connection to a dynamic URL with the help of jsoup. I am able to create a session with jsoup , but after creating the session need to navigate to the URL which is dynamic. Is there any way to pass values and click buttons in the webpage to reach the desired URL ?

Comment: JSoup is just for scrapping I think. What you want needs a WebDriver, you should check out https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver

Comment: You can do it with jsoup, just parse the page for the link, then perform another connect() on the link you parsed.  This question is really too broad though.